# Highest overall armor?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I wanted to make the tank build, trying to get the highest overall effective health. 
Smelter armor is good for fire def, havels for def, dark set for dark def. What would be the most balanced, elemental and physical armor combination?

Comment: Why don't you carry them all and use the armor most appropriate to your enemies? Even wearing the 'highest overall' armor wont beat the best suited armor for the area you're in.  If it is for PvP just look at the most common builds

Answer (score 1):

Lost sinners mask, dragon rider armor, havels guantlets, havels boots, havels greatshield with that said max out your vitality to 99 wear a third dragon ring and you're still light enough to roll around if you really want some nasty high defense try equipping flame quartz ring +2, Dark quartz ring +2, and Spell quartz ring +2

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a most balance element physical armor combination, since its mostly opinion based and it would take a lot of time to test everything.
Havel's set is in fact the most defensive set from all, but from my personal reasearch I cant tell you that the best head armor is the smelter demon one, so if you are searching for a good def/elemental combination i would go for smelter demon head piece and havel set.
Dark set has very weak excepted for dark, so it's not a good idea to combine that with the others

Answer (score 0):

**There is none that is good on all elements and physical damage**. So, you'll need to

**use something that has defence in what you struggle dodging**. Mage armor has

amazing elemental defence, but bad physical defence. In my opinion, I'm good at

dodging all sorts of spells, so I don't care about elemental defence. I use the

Alonne Knight captain set. **Armor with lighting and magic defence are super** **rare**,

you'll have to **stick with a mage/cleric set to have good defence against**

**lightning/magic.**